# Overflow condition in MIPS for subtraction of Unsigned numbers

Tags: assembly, mips, unsigned

When does overflow occurs in MIPS for subtraction of Unsigned numbers?

I couldn't find the answer on Google. I have design algo for overflow of addition of unsigned numbers but couldn't figure out about unsigned subtraction..

Can anybody tell me?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

When the subtrahend is greater than the minuend you'll get an overflow.

```
a - b, if b > a then set overflow
```

Comment: can you please explain how??

Comment: The answer looks pretty clear to me.  Can you give more detail on what needs to be clarified?

Comment: @Naruto Integer arithmetic on computers is circular. Both `-1` and `4,294,967,295‬` are represented as `FFFFFFFF` in hexadecimal, meaning to the CPU they are *the same number.* This seems weird, but it is the easiest and most sensible way to implement negative numbers on computer architecture. Otherwise, you'd have both positive and negative zero, and who wants that?